# Jmeter ForEach controller is not getting/taking all the values from regular expression variable results when match count set to -1

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter ForEach controller is not getting/taking all the values from regular expression variable results when match count set to -1.

Jmeter version: 3.1

Jmeter response is in JSON format

Jmeter TestPlan structure:

`ThreadGroup`

```
--Req1
```

`--Req2`

`---RegEx: with Match No. -1`
(Debug Sampler shows match count: 4 )

`Loop Controller`

`---ForEach Controller`

`----Http req using ForEach controller's output variable`

Run the test> it is able to successfully iterate through 3 variable values however not interating through one of the RegExp variable value.

[image]
[image]

New Image:
[image]

Please guide.

Comment: It seems that one is empty.can you show the response or title= values you are extracting from?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have added New Image, there is no empty value in the results.

Comment: You should use only for each controller.remove the loop controller

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. In my ForEach controller 'starting index' was 1 hence it was not considering the 0th index. Now also removed Loop, it is working as expected. Once again thanks for guiding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use only for each controller.remove the loop controller .

Notice in right click you can change controller next time.